# Getting location where a Box2d Body has been touched?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I'm making a libgdx game where the user can create a distance joint and a revolute joint on its own, so what I do whenever 2 bodies have been touched they are both added to an arrayList, then when a button is touched a joint will be created. The problem is that the joint are always at the center, so I was wondering if there is a way to get the location of the body where it was touched?, then set those locations as anchorPointA and anchorPointB.

Answer (score 0):

The first idea I get is a Gesture listener, see for example the [GestureDetector.GestureAdapter()](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/input/GestureDetector.GestureAdapter.html). Then you implement the touchDown method where you can get the x, y touch positions. To see wheter a body is touched, you might use the `Vector.dst()` method, but don't forget to unproject if you need.

Another idea might be to add an InputListener to your actor (which is connected to your body), but I haven't tried it yet.